# Как поставить верстку блока .container на моей img?

Tags: bootstrap

Верстаю сайт на bootstrap 4. Вопрос простой, но хочу всё правильно сделать?
Как поставить верстку блока .container на моей img? Чтобы была верстка на картинке

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Glavnaya</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- my css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <img src="images/back_header.jpg" class="w-100" alt="">
    <div class="container" >
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  </header>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: и всё сам решил

Answer (score 0):

Может быть кому-нибудь пригодится, как вариант:

```css
header {
  position: relative;
}

header .container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <header>
    <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" class="w-100" alt="">
    <div class="container" >
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Вариант с подложкой:

```css
header {
  position: relative;
}

header h1 {
  color: #fff;
}

header:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
}

header .container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 30;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   



<header>     
    <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" class="w-100" alt="">

    <div class="container" >
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>    
</header>
```